# Rating words from best to worst

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, geography

> In my personal classification, certain words are assigned a rating based on some criteria. The top rating is AA, and below it the ratings go from A all the way down to Z. Seventeen AA-class words are listed below.
>
> ```
> ants arms ingots limn mars nark nonvariant pi
> rams rank rhino rip san sulk suns tans wart
> ```
>
> Most words are unrated, whereas some words may qualify for multiple ratings. For example, **pair** would qualify for both an A-class and an S-class rating.
>
> To my knowledge, there is exactly one word with a Z rating. What is it?

Comment: From what list of words are these the only AA ones?

Comment: @ZanyG I used an online tool (can't really tell which one without giving away the method), but it doesn't seem they have a publicly available word list... I'll remove the word "all" since there may be some other words which are in the dictionary but not listed by that particular site.

Comment: rot13: Jryy, gur trbtencul gnt xvaqn fcbvyrq vg, qvqa'g vg?

Comment: @dquijada Hmm, I thought it would be too difficult without it. Too many options to consider... Then again I'm constantly amazed at how quickly people solve these puzzles so maybe it would have been figured out regardless.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The AA rated words are words which

> which anagram to a country capital with AA appended.

The seventeen are

> ants - Astana, arms - Asmara, ingots -Santiago, limn - Manila, mars - Asmara, nark - Ankara, nonvariant - Antananarivo, pi - Apia, rams - Asmara, rank - Ankara, rhino - Honiara, rip - Praia, san - Sanaa, sulk - Lusaka, suns - Nassau, tans - Astana, wart - Tarawa.

Following this rule a Z rated word is

> **barge** - Zagreb is the capital of Croatia.

Comment: How did you figure this out so quickly!?

Comment: @Tom is one of the best solvers!